# Way to use Google Search API to access Google Enchanced Events results?

Tags: web-scraping, google-search, google-search-api, google-search-platform

I am working to automate Google searches for events in a specific area. When manually searching for events, for example "concerts in Los Angeles" there is a form of enchanted rich results called "Events" that feature structured data like date, event title, host, etc.

I would like to automate the searching for these events, but cannot figure out an API or site that allows for the scraping of these Events blocks. Is there a google search keyword or other method in which I could isolate these events?